# Solving the PDE $ku_{xx}(x,t)=u_t(x,t)$ Using Fourier Transforms

Tags: proof-verification, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

> I am trying to solve the PDE $$ku_{xx}(x,t)=u_t(x,t),$$ given that $u(0,t)=u_0$ and $u(x,0)=0$.

Taking the Fourier transform with respect to $x$ gives, 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\hat{u}(w,t)+kw\hat{u}(w,t)=0,$$ where $\hat{u}(w,t)=\mathcal{F}_x(u(x,t)).$ The solution to this quasi-ODE is $$\hat{u}(w,t)=A(w)e^{-kw^2t}.$$ But I am unsure how to progress from here.

Comment: You will want to start by finding the inverse Fourier transform of $\hat{u}(w,t)$.

Comment: @D.B. Yep, but I'm unsure of where to use both the initial condition and the boundary condition. For instance, doesn't the initial condition imply that $A(w)=0$? Meaning that $\hat{u}(w,t)=0$. How can this be?

Comment: @D.B. Yes. So $$\mathcal{F}_x(u(x,0))=\mathcal{F}_x(0)\implies \hat{u}(x,0)=0.$$ Then $A(w)=0$.

Comment: Hmm.  Well the heat equation is dissipative, which means that the solution will lose energy over time (unless you had a forcing term).  So, the zero solution sounds reasonable.

Comment: But the answer is $u_0\text{erfc}(x/2\sqrt{kt})$, meaning that $\hat{u}(w,t)\neq 0$.

Comment: For the standard heat equation on $\mathbb{R}$, you cannot specify $u(0,t)$ for all $t$. All you can do is specify the initial heat distribution $u(x,0)$. However, if you are working on $x \ge 0$, then a condition $u(x,0)$ would make sense.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Given the way the question is written (yellow box), how can I solve this problem? I guess I could try solving the ODE using a Laplace transform. I'm so confused on how to proceed from my last line

Comment: $u(0,t)=u_0$ is not even consistent with $u(x,0)=0$, unless $u_0=0$. Are you supposed to be solving this problem for $x \ge 0$ or for all $-\infty < x < \infty$?

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts It actually doesn't specify. This is a poorly worded question. I'm going to assume that $x\in (0,\infty)$. Does this help to solve the problem?

Comment: If you're supposed to use the Fourier transform, then you can't assume $x\in (0,\infty)$. However, it would be consistent to assume an even solution in $x$, and transform accordingly.